# view inside a views, ajax load more bug

Tags: views, ajax

Basically I've created 2 views and one is supposed to be called inside the other one, I've done this call by overriding the style output of the main one.
The problem is because I'm using ajax load more, when I click on "load more" the new elements are displayed in the main view but also inside the other view.
Here how I call it

```
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
      <?php
        $counter++;
        if($counter == 4) {
          $view = views_get_view('twitter');
          $view->set_display('twitter');
          $view->pre_execute();
          $view->execute();
          $count = count( $view->result );
          print $view->render();
        } 
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: This could be issue with `views load more` module. You need to check that module.

Comment: yeah probably, I'll have a look

Comment: the prob was comming from the selector in the JS of the view load more module.